# Blank PHP pages when using php-fpm and nginx on a Debian VPS

Tags: php, nginx, debian, php-fpm

I keep receiving a blank page whenever I try to access a PHP page on my nginx webserver on a Debian VPS. nginx is working fine; I can access any normal HTML page. PHP-FPM is at least running, as I can start/restart it and when I stop it the PHP pages give me a 502 bad gateway error, which is normal.

But whenever FPM is running, any PHP page is blank without any errors. This leads me to believe there is a configuration error in FPM.

Here is my php-fpm.conf: http://pastebin.com/CSUuSzxx

Comment: Check the PHP error logs.

Comment: For those coming to this fresh, make sure you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423500/nginx-showing-blank-php-pages) – there are multiple answers that have worked for various people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, okay.

So I had logging and error displaying etc. turned on in php.ini, but the logfile location option was commented out. I uncommented it and changed the value to /var/log/php5.log and then went to check the pages again so it would display a blank page and log something to the file.

Instead, the page loaded fine.

A bit odd but I'll take it. Thanks Michael Hampton for the help.